# I received this mail by Google: We found an issue in the following area(s): Title

Tags: google-play-services, google-developers-console

I don't know what is "Title". How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe they rejected your app because they think the title of your app and the icon is impersonating another app. Maybe the name of your app is too similar to an app that already exists.